# SQL server unable to login from specific servers

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to setup a new MS SQL server, but i am having trouble connecting it to the main app servers.

Points to note and things i have tried:

- People can connect to the server remotely from their machines without any issue.
- Tried setting up and enabling all the ip configurations under the instance.
- Able to connect to remote shared paths between these servers.
- Able to see logs saying server is listening on 127.0.0.1 and ::1

Error seen:

Via IIS-

> Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed while
>   attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement.  This
>   could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was
>   unable to respond back in time.  The duration spent while attempting
>   to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=14800;
>   handshake=13501; ]

vis SQLCMD -

> Unable to complete Login process due to delay in opening server
>   connection.

Is there somewhere else i should be looking.? I am not sure if the issue is with the App server or DB server even.

Comment: `127.0.0.1` and `::1` are `localhost` (aka "me") in IPv4 and v6 respectively, so that doesn't say much. By "connect to the server remotely" do you means users can connect to something other than SQL Server, e.g. Remote Desktop, on the servers? In that case it could be a network issue that is restricting access to the SQL Server port number on the server, client, or any bit of networking hardware in between. Can users run SSMS locally and connect to the appropriate SQL Server instances on the servers?

Comment: `127.0.0.1` and `::1` are the localhost addresses, meaning the SQL Server will only accept connections from itself. Have you configured any other IP addresses to listen in SQL Server Configuration Manager > SQL Server Network Configuration > Protocols for MSSQLSERVER > TCP/IP?